# Turn off separator between windows names in tmux+powerline

Tags: tmux, powerline, byobu

Does anyone know how to hide this separator in byobu/tmux+powerline?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. In tmux it is a window option called a window-status-separator. You can set it in the .tmux.config by adding it after the powerline is initialized:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-separator ""
```

It overwrites the default separator (" "). Luckily, it does not affect any styling of powerline. Maybe someone knows a powerline specific answer. Feel free to comment.